# django postgresql insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: database, django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship, django-orm

I'm getting the error message:

> insert or update on table "quizzer_progress" violates foreign key
>   constraint. DETAIL:  Key (word_id)=(4700) is not present in table
>   "quizzer_alone_words".

but it makes no sense.
I have these 3 tables in models.py:

```
class Progress(models.Model):
  success = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  fail = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  word = models.ForeignKey(Word, related_name='word_progress', blank=True, null=True)

class WordLesson(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True)
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Words_from_lessons')
  words = models.ManyToManyField('Alone_Words', blank=True)
  min_age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  max_age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Alone_Words(models.Model):
  lesson = models.ForeignKey(WordLesson, related_name='lesson_of_the_word', blank=True, default=1)
  word = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
  position = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

As you can see, the table where I'm trying to save data has nothing to do with the one that "violates foreign key constraint"

Anyone can tell me what's happening????

**NOTE:** the code failing is this one ->

```
p = Progress(success =0,fail = 0,total =0,word = myword)
p.save()
```

Comment: Where does `myword` come from?

Comment: It comes from: `for myword in Word.objects.all():` in the previous line